# If you're flying VFR in controlled airspace and in contact with ATC, do you need permission to change altitudes?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control

I think the controller sometimes gives altitudes for VFR traffic to fly, but do pilots actually need permission to change their altitude?

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about?

Comment: The US, thanks.

Comment: In Bravo, where you are cleared in, and the area is large, I would say yes.
In Charlie or Delta, it would depend on how much other traffic was around.

Comment: The question should NOT be marked as a duplicate: you should have a *clearance* in a controlled airspace (except E for VFR) regardless of whether you requested flight following or not. But the answer is really pretty much the same as during the flight following: it depends on airspace class and ATC instructions, and you should always follow ATC instructions.